# Does altering a Sequence from NOORDER to ORDER affect already-cached sequence?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a sequence with `NOORDER` in Oracle. I need to alter the sequence to support `ORDER`. I have given the `CACHE 20` for my sequence.

If I alter to `ORDER`, will it effect the already cached sequences and require a DB restart?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only circumstance in which ORDER is useful is when using sequences to determine the order in which the value was requested in a RAC environment. Is that your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your database a RAC database? If yes and if you strictly need ordered value you have to eliminate the sequence cache too.
Id does not grant you the absence of gaps. For example in a case of a rollback, you will have gap/s in your ordered column.

The execution of an alter sequence command will invalidate you seqeunce's cache.

Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks Giova for the reply. My database is RAC database. I need the ordered value. Gaps in the ordered values is no issue. And also i need to have the **CACHE 20** for my sequence. Does the ordered value with gaps possible for the sequence with cache in RAC Database?

Comment: No... If you use cache you can not be sure about ordered values. Each database instance will cache a different subset of sequence values so in a two instance configuration can have 11-31 and the second 32-52.

Comment: Thank you very much @Giova. This explanation is very helpful.